# SSH Single-Sign On with Kerberos

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, kerberos, single-sign-on

I want to authenticate with SSH through Kerberos SSO. Now when I'm logged in with my user principal on `sourcehost` I get my Kerberos Ticket but can't use it to SSH into `targethost`.

The problem seems to be the hostname. I have a host principal `host/targethost.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM` but no matter if I `ssh targethost` or `ssh targethost.example.com` it gets translated into host principal `host/targethost@EXAMPLE.COM` (see error message below), which doesn't exist.

I might be wrong, but I think it should be the other way around and both `ssh targethost` and `ssh targethost.example.com` should be translated into host principal `host/targethost.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM`.

Here's the error:

```
$ ssh targethost.example.com -v
...
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server host/targethost@EXAMPLE.COM not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server host/targethost@EXAMPLE.COM not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
...
debug1: Next authentication method: password
testuser@targethost.example.com's password:
```

Can anybody explain how the host principal is derived from the hostname and how this can be configured (I'm on Ubuntu by the way)?

---

**Edit:**

[grawity's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1166101/578958) led me to a solution that I think is a good one for my configuration.

- I found in Garman's Kerberos book that **KDC-side canonicalization** was the preferred way.
- For my LDAP-backed KDC I found in the Kerberos documentation (at the bottom of [this page](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/conf_ldap.html)) the way how this can be realized.

So after creating the host principal with `kdadmin.local` / `addprinc` with the FQDN I had to add an alias to the new principal entry in LDAP by running `ldapmodify` with the following input:

```
dn: krbPrincipalName=host/targethost.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM,cn=EXAMPLE.COM,cn=krbContainer,dc=example,dc=com
replace: krbCanonicalName
krbCanonicalName: host/targethost.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
-
add: krbPrincipalName
krbPrincipalName: host/targethost@EXAMPLE.COM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, Kerberos has used reverse-DNS to canonicalize the principal name. That is, after resolving `targethost.example.com` to an IP address, it tries to resolve the address back to the "canonical" name, and uses that for the principal.

If your `targethost` was resolved via /etc/hosts, then the *first* name in the corresponding line will be used as the "canonical" name:

```
# good:
1.2.3.4  targethost.example.com  targethost

# bad:
1.2.3.4  targethost  targethost.example.com
```

If you want, you can turn off DNS-based canonicalization entirely via /etc/krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
    dns_canonicalize_hostname = false
```

...and simply create two principals for the host – one for the short name, one for the long one. (That's actually what Active Directory does, and it's not unlike how SSL/TLS behaves – it's always safer to directly use the user input rather than ask DNS.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints! My /etc/hosts files were already "good" and running `nslookup targethost` and then `nslookup` for the IP resulted in FQDN. Changing them to "bad" didn't change anything. I suppose there are various configurations possible for hostname resolution.

Comment: I found the solution thanks to the term "canonicalization" you mentioned. I'll add it to the question. I did not try to turn off canonicalization off. Thanks again!

Comment: @bassjoe: `nslookup` is the wrong tool to check, though. Use `getent ahosts`.

Comment: On a fresh Fedora 27 installation, after ipa-client-install, I needed to modify this entry in the `/etc/krb5.conf` to make it possible to run `ssh shortname` and have kerberos auth work like it did in Fedora 26 and before.